# Where are all the new international readers coming from?

Tags: discussion

Just an interesting observation that most of the recent activity is from international users.
Sort of cool, but I wonder how it relates to the lack of activity from users here in the US.

This question doesn't help the site much as much as it just feeds my curiosity.

Comment: I am from the UK but would also be interested to know the international reach of the site. Do you have a break down for countries?

Comment: Interesting that it took 4 years for someone to wander over to the meta side is this site and found my question about international users.  I don't have any of the data obviously.  I don't know who actually runs the site, aside from the moderators doing their thing, but I find it sad that there isn't any real activity over here on the meta side. And that there is no clear care in the ownership.  I understand StackExchange is a big entity, but no one has taken up the homebrewing SE torch it seems.

Comment: South of Brazil. We've got some good foruns in portuguese, but most of the stuff I read is in english, so this site, homebrewerstalk, byo and books are my main resource of info about brewing. It helps me get used to the terms so I find it easier to buy stuff on ebay or amazon :)